# JSF how to submit a form via onchange of a selectOneRadio

Tags: java, jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

I'm trying to submit a form when a selectOneRadio value is selected. I have the code below, but it's not getting inside my `#{contentEditorBacking.addNewsArticle}`.

Does anyone know how i can get into the method when a selectOneRadio is clicked?

```
<p:panel header="News Article Title">
    <h:panelGrid columns="2">
        <h:outputLabel for="title" value="Title" style="font-weight: bold;"/>
        <p:inputText id="title" required="true" value="#{contentEditorBacking.newsTitle}" />
        <h:outputLabel value="Site" />
        <p:selectOneRadio value="#{contentEditorBacking.selectedNews}" layout="pageDirection" onchange="submit()">
            <f:selectItem itemLabel="Public" itemValue="Public" />
            <f:selectItem itemLabel="Member" itemValue="Member" />
        </p:selectOneRadio>
        <p:commandButton value="submit" action="#{contentEditorBacking.addNewsArticle}" />
    </h:panelGrid>
</p:panel>
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Two problems:

- To intercept on "change" in radio buttons (and checkboxes) You need the `click` event instead.
- The `<p:commandButton>` is by default an ajax button which isn't prepared for synchronous submits like as performed by JS `submit()`.

Just use `<p:ajax>` instead so that the submit is performed by ajax. Note that you don't need to specify the `event` attribute, it defaults to `click` already.

```html
<p:selectOneRadio value="#{contentEditorBacking.selectedNews}" layout="pageDirection">
    <f:selectItem itemLabel="Public" itemValue="Public" />
    <f:selectItem itemLabel="Member" itemValue="Member" />
    <p:ajax listener="#{contentEditorBacking.addNewsArticle}" />
</p:selectOneRadio>
<p:commandButton value="submit" action="#{contentEditorBacking.addNewsArticle}" />
```

---

**Update** as per the comments, you seem to want to navigate to another page with a parameter. The `addNewsArticle()` method should then look like as follows so that it is compatible with both `<p:ajax listener>` and `<p:commandButton action>`.

```
public void addNewsArticle() throws IOException {
    ExternalContext ec = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext();
    ec.redirect(ec.getRequestContextPath() + "/next.xhtml?action=add");
}
```

Comment: In my addNewsArticle, I'm returning a string with the url + a query string so i can't do an ajax submit.

Comment: You wasn't clear about that in your initial question. You have nowhere stated the concrete functional requirement. Just go for the first approach then. By the way, if the method does nothing else than just returning a string, then you could also just put that sole string straight in `action` attribute like so `action="next.xhtml?action=add"` or so. Don't forget to disable the ajax behaviour :)

Comment: Sorry for not specifying that, i was trying to keep the question short and to the point. I'm actually checking a couple of things and then generating a string so i need to use the backing method.

Comment: If i change `onchange` to `onclick`, nothing happens, but if i leave it at `onchange`, it refreshes the page, but it doesn't get in my backer. If i actually click the submit button, it does get into my backing method

Comment: What if you use `h:` instead of `p:`? If it works then the `p:selectOneRadio` has apparently generated improper HTML. Verify the generated HTML source in webbrowser if PrimeFaces has done it as you expected.

Comment: Please describe "does not work" in detail. What exactly happens and what exactly not? I do not have your webapp/code in front of me so I could debug/track it myself. I have by the way updated the answer how the second approach would work out for you.

Comment: Your updated answer seems to work for me. I was not aware that you can redirect from the backing bean.

Comment: You're welcome. I have removed the first approach from the answer for the sake that. Perhaps PrimeFaces just didn't generate proper HTML or you have more buttons in the same form which would get precedence, etc.